# GWT Datagrid horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear

Tags: gwt

i have a small screen and i want the horizontal scrollbar on datagrid to appear automatically.
i've used:
dataGrid.setMinimumTableWidth(1500, Unit.PX);

this sets the width both the scrollbar still not appear

any tip?

Comment: The tricky is use: dataGrid.setMinimumTableWidth(width, Unit.PX);

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. When using DatGrid make sure you place it within a ResizeLayoutPanel. Set the height of the panel to xxx PX and the width to a yyy %. Then for the DataGrid just set width to 100%.  Column widths units can be EM, PCT, or PX. In fact do not set all column widths to total 100%, otherwise you'll get funky display issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I tested out this code, both scrollbars show.

```
  <g:ResizeLayoutPanel height="480px" width="760px">
       <c:DataGrid width="100%"  addStyleNames='{style.cellTable}' ui:field="testResultTable"/>
  </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
```